# Where do I have to specify the parameters and special sequences for SignTool in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, code-signing, signtool

Here's the documentation article for `SignTool`: [SignTool](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_signtool).

I'm not really sure where should I specify the `SignTool` parameters and special sequences. Is it in the `[Setup]` section or *in the compiler IDE (via the Tools | Configure Sign Tools... menu)* or both? If I have specified all the parameters in the compiler IDE, do I have to do that again in the `[Setup]` section? Also, I don't really understand this part:

> byparam=$p
>
> Note: for security reasons you should give a unique name to any Sign
> Tool set to $p, and not use a byparam name copied from this example.
> Consider what happens if you #include a third-party file that says:
>
> [Setup] SignTool=byparam format c:

How does that `$p` sequence really work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [`SignTool` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_signtool), you specify, which sign tool definition you want to use in that particular script. The tool can be defined in IDE or using `/S` [compiler commandline switch](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=compilercmdline).

The `SignTool` directive can contain additional parameters, which can be referred to by the definition using the `$p` *special sequence*. That allows you the flexibility to define part of the command in the script and part in the definition. The choice is completely yours. *To be honest, I do not really understand the reason for this, as the same flexibility can be achieved using Inno Setup preprocessor. There might be some historical reason. I do not know if the `SignTool` predates the built-in preprocessor, or if it was the other way around.*

Anyway, the above means that these three are equivalent:

**Everything in the definition**

- Definition:

  ```
  mysigntool=signtool.exe sign /a /n $qMy Common Name$q /t http://... $f
  ```
- Script:

  ```
  [Setup]
  signtool=mysigntool
  ```

---

**Part in the definition, part in the script**

- Definition:

  ```
  mysigntool=signtool.exe sign /a $p
  ```
- Script:

  ```
  [Setup]
  signtool=mysigntool /n $qMy Common Name$q /t http://... $f
  ```

---

**Everything in the script**

- Definition:

  ```
  anysigntool=$p
  ```
- Script:

  ```
  [Setup]
  signtool=anysigntool signtool.exe sign /a /n $qMy Common Name$q /t http://... $f
  ```